# load and unload a message

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I create a message when a process starts (BOOL YES) and I am trying to make it go away when it ends (BOOL NO), debugging shows me stepping through the whole function both in the beginning and end, however the message is still there.

Where am I going wrong?  Thank you in advance

```
-(void) loadStillLoadingMessage:(BOOL)yesNo{
CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
CGFloat screenWidth = screenSize.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenSize.height;
UILabel *loading = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((screenWidth/2)-75,(screenHeight)-140,300,40)]autorelease];

loading.text = @"still loading";
loading.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
loading.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
loadingLabel = loading;
[self.view addSubview:loadingLabel];
[loadingLabel setHidden:YES];
if (yesNo == YES) {
    [loadingLabel setHidden:NO];
}else if (yesNo ==NO){
    [loadingLabel setHidden:YES];
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method is creating a `UIView` whenever it is called. So the `UIView` you create and show on the first time is different to the `UIView` you create, show and then hide the second time. You need to look at instance variables (declaring a variable in the header file).

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is you didn't remove the old loading from the self.view.

```
-(void) loadStillLoadingMessage:(BOOL)yesNo{
    CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenSize.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenSize.height;
    UILabel *loading = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((screenWidth/2)-75,    (screenHeight)-140,300,40)]autorelease];

    loading.text = @"still loading";
    loading.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    loading.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    loadingLabel = loading;

    //removing the previous label from the self.view if exist
    loadingLabel.tag = 999;
    [[self.view viewWithTag:999] removeFromSuperview];

    [self.view addSubview:loadingLabel];
    [loadingLabel setHidden:YES];
    if (yesNo == YES) {
         [loadingLabel setHidden:NO];
    }else if (yesNo ==NO){
      [loadingLabel setHidden:YES];
    }
```

}